# How can I infer optional properties in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I have the following type definition for a database schema:

```js
type Schema<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: SchemaType<T[K]>
}

interface SchemaType<T> {
  optional: boolean
  validate(t: T): boolean
}
```

Here's an object that implements it:

```js
const userSchema = {
  name: {
    optional: true,
    validate(name: string) {
      return name.length > 0 && name.length < 30
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to be able to infer the generic type `T` in `Schema` based on the `userSchema` object. This is doable without too much effort using TypeScript's `infer` keyword:

```js
type extractType<T> = T extends Schema<infer X> ? X : null

// User is inferred as { name: string }
type User = extractType<typeof userSchema>
```

Even better, I'm able to infer the `User` type indirectly:

```js
class Model<T> {
  constructor(private schema: Schema<T>) {}
}

// userModel is inferred as type Model<{name: string}>
const userModel = new Model(userSchema)
```

However, I would like to be able to infer `User` as `{ name?: String }`, where `name` is optional because its `optional` property is set to true. Is there a way to do this?

### Some related TypeScript features

Here are some potentially useful TypeScript features I ran across while working on this.

1. TypeScript has [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions), which is similar to the kind of type inference I'm trying to achieve.
2. Although the `optional` field on the `userSchema` above is inferred as a `boolean`, it's possible to infer it as a boolean literal using `as const`.

   ```js
   // userSchema is inferred as
   // { name: { optional: true, validate(name: string): boolean } }
   // instead of
   // { name: { optional: boolean, validate(name: string): boolean } }
   const userSchema = {
     name: {
       optional: true as const,
       validate(name: string) {
         return name.length > 0 && name.length < 30
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   Requiring this isn't ideal, but I'm not sure it's avoidable.
3. I tried using [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) like in the `extractType` implementation above to define `Schema` in a more limiting way:

   ```js
   // The below interface essentially says:
   //   if T[K] is an optional property
   //     then -> optional is set to true
   //     else -> optional is set to false.
   // I was hoping TypeScript could reverse this when inferring the type:
   //   if optional is set to true
   //     then -> T[K] is an optional property
   //     else -> T[K] is a required property
   type Schema<T> = {
     [K in keyof T]: undefined extends T[K]
       ? OptionalSchemaType<T[K]> // Same as SchemaType but with optional: true
       : RequiredSchemaType<T[K]> // Same as SchemaType but with optional: false
   }

   const userModel = new Model(userSchema) // Error!
   ```

   Unfortunately, TypeScript's type inference isn't smart enough to be able to infer a type this complex.

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to achieve is possible, but any help or alternatives are very much appreciated. :)

Comment: `interface Schema<T> {[K in keyof T]: SchemaType<T[K]>}` is not valid TS; Presumably you mean `type Schema<T> = ...` instead.

Comment: Fixed! Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you might well need to write `true as const` or `true as true` or something like that, since the compiler will tend to widen boolean literals to type `boolean` unless they are declared in a context in which the compiler expects a narrower type.  One possible approach to avoid the explicit cast is to use a helper function that returns its input which it expects to be in such a narrower-type context:

```
const asSchema = <S extends Record<keyof S, { optional: B }>, B extends boolean>(
    s: S
) => s;

const userSchema = asSchema({
    name: {
        optional: true,
        validate(name: string) {
            return name.length > 0 && name.length < 30
        }
    },
    age: {
        optional: false,
        validate(age: number) {
            return age >= 0 && age < 200;
        }
    }
});
```

You can verify that the type of `userSchema` is:

```
/* const userSchema: {
    name: {
        optional: true;
        validate(name: string): boolean;
    };
    age: {
        optional: false;
        validate(age: number): boolean;
    };
} */
```

It may be worth it to use a helper function if you're planning on creating a lot of these things; or you may rather just write `optional: false as false`.  Anyway, moving on:

---

I think you're going to need to calculate the type directly instead of relying on type inference.  The direct approach requires a lot of explicitly writing out what parts of the type turn into what.  Let's come up with some utility types:

The `PartialPartial<T, K>` type takes a type `T` and a set of its keys `K` and returns a new type like `T` except that all the properties indexed by `K` are optional.  So, `PartialPartial<{a: string, b: number}, "a">` is `{a?: string, b: number}`.

```
type PartialPartial<T, K extends keyof T> = Partial<Pick<T, K>> & Omit<T, K> extends
    infer O ? { [P in keyof O]: O[P] } : never;
```

The `KeysMatching<T, V>` type takes a type `T` and returns all the keys of `T` whose properties are assignable to `V`.  So, `KeysMatching<{a: string, b: number}, number>` is `"b"`.

```
type KeysMatching<T, V> = { [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? K : never }[keyof T];
```

And now for `ExtractType<T>`.  Given a schema-like `T`, first map over each of its properties and pull out the first parameter to the `validate()` method.  Then, take the whole result, and make optional all the properties whose `optional` property is `true`:

```
type ExtractType<T extends { [K in keyof T]: SchemaType<any> }> = PartialPartial<{
    [K in keyof T]: Parameters<T[K]['validate']>[0]
}, KeysMatching<T, { optional: true }>>
```

Testing it out on the `userSchema` above:

```
type UserThing = ExtractType<typeof userSchema>;
/* type UserThing = {
    name?: string | undefined;
    age: number;
} */
```

Looks good.

---

If we're giving up on type inference, this means you can't easily have `Model<T>` constructed by `Schema<T>` (at least not with standard `class` statements).  One way around this is to have `Model` be generic in the schema type `S`, and use `ExtractType<S>` wherever you would want to use `T`.  You could even put that `T` in the type definition, so you have `Model<S, T>` where `S` is the schema type and `T` is the extracted type:

```
class Model<S extends Record<keyof S, SchemaType<any>>, T extends ExtractType<S> = ExtractType<S>> {
    constructor(private schema: S) { }
}

const userModel = new Model(userSchema);
// S is typeof userSchema
// T is {name?: string, age: number}
```

---

My caveat about standard `class` statements: you could decide to describe the static side of `Model` via a `ModelConstructor` interface which allows you to specify a different sort of generic relationship from what is normally available between the `constructor` method and the instance type:

```
interface MyModelConstructor {
    new <S extends Record<keyof S, SchemaType<any>>>(schema: S): MyModel<ExtractType<S>>;
}
interface MyModel<T> {
    something: T;
}
const MyModel = Model as any as MyModelConstructor;
```

And test it:

```
const myUserModel = new MyModel(userSchema);
/* const myUserModel: MyModel<{
    name?: string | undefined;
    age: number;
}> */
```

Here you can see that `new MyModel(userSchema)` produces a `MyModel<{name?: string, age: number}>`.  That's great, but you'll find yourself having to write out redundant interface declarations for the static/instance side of your class, and then assigning your other class constructor to it.  The duplication might not be worth it; it's up to you.

---

Okay, I realize that was a lot of stuff.  Hope it helps you.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAygxgCwgWwIYB4AqA+KBeKAbwFgAoKCqAbQGkoBLAOygGsIQB7AMykwF0AXLEQpUmcBCy0+2MgF8yZJsAgAnLqjjR4SNOMhZcJcpQ5hg9Do1QAbIQCMOHGxFSMylKADdb9ACaoKgAUwEKYAJQOTi5u8oqkcFYAzsBQqEk6ovhQ6DBQEAAeKox+SVAAShCJqn7obJw8MAA0RFBmFla2QgBCUHLYLb2FxaVQjs6ujNhBHpRJQjBk4fi4SQDc8YmMKVAArklqmWjZ6UeoQcae1sgQQpeepuaW1nZQwKq7EE2zD96+AcFrrcoClVEwAObLe6-TyqCDAXaqZhAgB0LkY4OACCguAADFAAGQEqCo9GY7HoKAAZlxPweChMFDk30ZaXBwOhD3azy6UA0NgOLJhfxs-kCECCqHZQkYu2Q9jUULpwrhCKRbOg2AI+KJGpyUAATLjcRtWZ4Geb5OFTQB6ABUUC2O32hxEaDudKBHrNjw6LyE70+puFPlFAIlXpB7whkTG0UmwcockTFClHOVvp5r35BxTD1DYuCaZlcoVqlj4xijDzyfkUDtNvi8VAkCgAAVUKoLLYO136LYsC06MMICUyvVuLxcARe92bOg2-Q4CxB1AaNhcMSAPLIejAVfr-JFUelOlMLhqKBbqAAflaVDbDGYE54W8EV4ffD6UBlEC8alNMgW2gGh2CSABZQJEAhVcADVp3vOgmFYdhJ34ABaG8wmkI8RjKWDbzXH8ST-S85CoF9eD4QDSGAqAAFEilUTRgH0SRMFwk8ykIagkOfVCeH4BY3TECR0DcEBcH6bJZ37GxZIHTlaCfFCGiooRe1QG4VFUJIpBoPgqAAcgLcMjJkKhcT4eQhzAyDgGgjFVx47lOleQNoH6WRSGbCQoAAVQOVRMAQCFskY94WLY9BgMnF1VDObBbQdOjArUEKwoIHjPS0iAsKjMEMSgAAfPYSggLgmAgPw82LElSwAusG02Gx0jKcCOD8CB5zyEcxwqKoOBqOoBNgFozmiiSNxaDi+tGCLmLgVixJgBCFqilaNyIOknUDJahqCMAwR8FQQREhYoT6OIfISZJUnijqupsbJGAgAB3KBHu6oJ4rOa0yBtG1YAYMpYp4X6RIBoGOPobigXy0EIRaOrZXlNQGXiZQ1A0LRPpAL6bAAYTuj59tUbbWVej7ck4-rKmqWpKOaYRdFEgwpo3IIknO2BY3A-HOu69B1qW6LVqS66sfUTRoH5gnDApzwkg4bTQoxMJTQZXa8YJ7JdfSNJGBANJ2oFp7ie2PbgCG01teQEA0tUXWCCpnXBZsH6gr+5LHTuqB7cdgmhDl930E5eGhERorSt2crKtemq6RRhrVE13AGyAA)

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I was looking for. I'm not sure if this is what you were trying to get at, but I believe it is possible to use a function to achieve the effect of `MyModelConstructor` but without the interface duplication. Here's what I used: `function createModel<S extends ..., T extends ...>(schema: S): Model<T> { return new Model<T>(schema) }`, where `Model` is the same but without the `S` type variable.